# Cross posting with Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I was recently sent to [Algorithms for calculating vertex normals in 2D polygon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/160344/8635) via the newsletter, it seemed like an interesting problem so I took a shot at it and got an accepted answer. I later stumbled across the same question asked by the same user on stack overflow, I've commented with a link on the question above, but I guess I was wondering what the policy on this is? It seems like it could be on topic on both sites, and it looks like there are good answers on both, so perhaps tis isn't an issue?

On the other hand it seems like most of the technical questions on this site would be on topic on Stack Overflow, so is it right to try and decide to post on the one which seems like the best fit, or should it actually be encouraged to cross-post?

Comment: Thanks for asking this in meta. Unfortunately, it has been asked before, and the policy has not changed since then. It's not only a [gamedev.se] policy, it's a [network wide policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I have closed the question you linked to because of that. The general guide we give is that the question should be asked on the site that has the most chances to receive the best answer. If the question is in the context of gamedev, perhaps it's better asking it here instead of there.

Comment: Here are related questions: [Programming Questions: Here or “Belongs on Stackoverflow”?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow) - [How do you decide when to post here vs. on SO?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-do-you-decide-when-to-post-here-vs-on-so/374#374) - [Generic programming questions are off-topic, period. Right?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/generic-programming-questions-are-off-topic-period-right)